# Pitch analysis in Audacity

Tags: pitch, analysis

For documenting and practicing music/ recitation styles, I wanted the kind of pitch analysis I see in this tweet: https://twitter.com/pattaprateek/status/1187095197911404545
[image]

How do I get something like that in Audacity? (The spectrogram view, where my octave looks as shown below, is a step in the right direction, but not as good/ clear).
[image]

Comment: Which version of audacity? AFAIK audacity can not do that. There may be some VST plug ins you could get to do it. You might do better with some sort of FFT to analyse your frequencies inside audacity.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Praat which has spectral and pitch analysis built in.

Here is a video explaining how this is done.